# Read/Unread cell (using drawrect)

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview, drawrect

My app downloading posts from internet to UITableViewCell. When user taps on cell, i am need to set this article as read (like on Mail.app). I dont know how to do that. 
I am adding url (when user press cell) to database (like "url|url|url"), open detail view. And when he goes back to UITableView checking existing url in DB. Table now is too slow!
Can u help me and say what other method i can use to do that? Like in mail.app. I am using custom cell and code in drawRect method. Please, help

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
            NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray array];
            if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]!=nil)
    [array addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]];
            NSUInteger indexOfObject = [array count]>0?[array indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]:100000;  //I add this, because row don't want update using updateRowAtIndexPath

            QuickCell *cell = (QuickCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil || (indexOfObject!=NSNotFound && indexOfObject!=100000))
            {
                cell = [[[QuickCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 68.0);
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                if([self.subject count]>0)
            {
                [self.allImages addObject:[NSNull null]];
                NSString *userNameLJ = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.journalurl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                userNameLJ = [userNameLJ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://"
                                                                   withString:@""];
                userNameLJ = [userNameLJ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".livejournal.com"
                                                                   withString:@""];
                userNameLJ = [userNameLJ stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"community/"
                                                                   withString:@""];
                NSString *postURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://m.livejournal.com/read/user/%@/%@",userNameLJ,[self.ditemid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


                NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [dict setObject:[self.subject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"title"];
                [dict setObject:[Utilities replaceForCell:[Utilities flattenHTML:[self.entry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] forKey:@"description"];

                if([[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM read WHERE posts=?;",postURL] count]>0)
            {
                //if this post is read
                [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"highlighted"];
            }   
                else {
                    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"highlighted"];
                }


            [dict setObject:[self.journalname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"nick"];

            [cell setContentForCell:dict];

                BOOL trueOrFalse = [[self.allImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]?YES:NO;
            if(trueOrFalse)
        {
            if (tableView.dragging == NO && tableView.decelerating == NO)
            {
                    //if no image cached now, download it
                if(indexPath.row<6 && self.updating==YES)
                    [self startDownloading:indexPath];
                if(self.updating==NO)
                    [self startDownloading:indexPath];
            }

            }
            else
            {
                [cell setImageForCell:[self.allImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }

            }

                if(indexOfObject!=NSNotFound && indexOfObject!=100000)
                {
                       //delete this row from userdefaults
                    [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject];
                    if([array count]>0)
                        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"readPostS"];
                    else [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"readPostS"];

                }
            }


            return cell;
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////-(void)viewWillApear
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSMutableArray *readPosts = [NSMutableArray array];
                if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]!=nil)
                {
                    [readPosts addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]];
                    self.read = (NSMutableArray*)[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM read;"];
                    for(int i=0;i<[readPosts count];i++)
                    {

                    [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[[readPosts objectAtIndex:i] intValue] inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                    }
                }

///////////////////////////////////////////////
///////THIS FILE OPENS POSTS FOR READING
///////////////////////////////////////////////
if([[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM read WHERE posts=?;",self.postURL] count]==0)
    {
        [database executeNonQuery:@"INSERT INTO read VALUES (?);",self.postURL];

        NSMutableArray *defaults = [NSMutableArray array];
        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]!=nil)
            defaults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"readPostS"]];
        [defaults addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.currentIndex]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:defaults forKey:@"readPostS"];
    }
```

---

Ok. I think, my code is to bad and u can understand, what i am doing here) Answer on other question. How i can update hidden cells? User see only 6 cell in a moment, i need to update, for example, 10 cells. How? 
Or, how reload cell, if it allready exists? Lets say -

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
QuickCell *cell = (QuickCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[QuickCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 68.0);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


.........}
```

now cell exists and if i call reload data nothing happen. And reloadCellAtIndexPath does not working too, because cell has unique identifier and ixists.

HOW I CAN RELOAD CELL AND CALL DRAWRECT AGAIN?))

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this functionality by adding your code in the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//Add the indexPath.row values in an array.
}
```

Add the custom functionality (like showing Title in BOLD for unread) in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//Check if the indexPath.row is available in the array
//If yes then Normalize the fonts
//Else Keep them BOLD.

}
```

Comment: yes. But problem here - user can read posts without returning on main page, like on Mail.app. He can read, for example, 10 posts. When he go back, only one row in cell will be unread. I tried use NSUserDefaults, but, i think, Apple have a bug. One moment. I show a code

Comment: Then you need to update your array when the user taps the next button for reading the next article just as Mail App.

Comment: All working like a charm, BUT when user update all posts on main tab, all read posts now UNREAD and when he press update again evrething allright, and then press update again.......etc. WTF?))

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're really doing some drawing, don't implement in `drawRect:`. I don't know you're specific code, so that may not be correct in your case.

To reload the entire table (*all* cells), look at UITableView's `- (void)reloadData`

To reload a specific cell, look at UITableView's `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` and use it to reload the cell in question.